# Android Google Maps current location bearing

Tags: android, google-api, android-location

I'm currently using Google Maps on Android, but I'm not sure how to rotate the map to show the users current facing direction.

When I set:

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

I notice that the current marker has a small bearing arrow (when phone is tilted, etc).

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
}

private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(latLng)
            .zoom(16.0f)
            .bearing(location.getBearing())
            .build();

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos));
}
```

This successfully updates the markers position on the map based on locations.  However, how can I change the facing direction of the marker by rotating the map, based on the phones yaw tilting.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener;
private Sensor accelerometer;
private Sensor magnetometer;
private float[] mGravity;
private float[] mGeomagnetic;
private Float azimut;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    sensorEventListener= new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
                mGravity = event.values;
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
                mGeomagnetic = event.values;
            if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
                float R[] = new float[9];
                float I[] = new float[9];
                boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
                if (success) {
                    float orientation[] = new float[3];
                    SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
                    azimut = orientation[0]; // orientation contains: azimut, pitch and roll
                    float degrees = (float) Math.toDegrees(azimut);
                    /**
                     * TRY THIS TO UPDATE YOUR CAMERA
                     * degrees you can use as bearing
                     * CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition( myLatLng, 15, 0, degrees);
                     * map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition),200, null);
                     **/
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}
```